# Using "this" with another, outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery's multiple selectors and set `on()` on them and then using "`$(this)`" implement something I need. This should look like this:

```
$(".one, .two, .three").on("someEvent", function () {
  $(this).something;
});
```

But, I want to move `$(this).something;` to its own function, something like that:

```
function outSideFunction() {
  $(this).something;
}
$(".one, .two, .three").on("someEvent", function () {
  outSideFunction();
});
```

But as you probably understand, this isn't really working. Is there some workaround this, so I could still use `this` in outside function?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to save state of this? If so, just store it in var like so: "var self = this;", and use self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass your callback function name and than use freely `$(this)` inside your function

```
function outSideFunction() {
  $(this).css({color: "red"}); // for example 
}

$(".one, .two, .three").on("someEvent", outSideFunction);
```

Here are some other ways:

#### bind

```
function outSideFunction() {
  $(this).css({color: "red"});
}

$(".one, .two, .three").bind("click", function(){
  outSideFunction.bind(this)();
  // Other stuff here
});
```

#### `this` as argument

```
function outSideFunction( that ) {
  $(that).css({color: "red"});
}

$(".one, .two, .three").on("click", function() {
  outSideFunction(this);
  // Other stuff here
});
```

#### $.proxy

```
function outSideFunction() {
  $(this).css({color: "red"});
}

$(".one, .two, .three").on("click", $.proxy(outSideFunction, this.selector));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `bind` `this` to a value:

```
function outSideFunction() {
     $(this).something;
}
$(".one, .two, .three").on("click", function () {
     outSideFunction.bind(this)();
});
```

Example:

```js
function outSideFunction() {
 $(this).remove();
}
$(".one, .two, .three").on("click", function () {
  outSideFunction.bind(this)();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
 Click to remove.
</div>
```

Comment: There are two seperate methods here.  `bind` in JavaScript and `bind` in jQuery. `bind` in jQuery refers to an event happening, like click.  `bind` in JavaScript refers to setting what `this` is.  They are **very** different.  This method does have certain functions like if you were to do a `setInterval` where you wanted access to `this`.

Comment: Thank you. Then is is also a valuable answer :)